# Dataset engineering Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I am trying to modify a CSV dataset with the Python Pandas package.
I have a "time" column (column num 5) that has 51 days and ~4K on records for each day.

I want to minimize the dataset to 35 days with 24 random records per day.

I am using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file_name = "filename"
data = pd.read_csv('path/to/the/file/'+file_name+".csv")
df = data.sort_values(data.columns[5])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

new_df=df
new_df.iloc[:,5]= pd.to_datetime(new_df.iloc[:,5])
new_df=new_df[(new_df.iloc[:,5] < '08/10/2018')]
```

Now I have 35 days with 4K records per day.
My thought was to create an empty Pandas DataFrame and to add by iteration 24 samples of each day, using the following code:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for date in new_df.iloc[:,5].unique():
    day = new_df[(new_df.iloc[:,5] == date)].sample(n=24)
    final_df.append(day)
print(final_df)
```

but it seems that the DF is steal empty:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Can someone direct me to the right solution? :)

Comment: `append` isn't inplace; but also you better not append in a loop, please see the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Comment: Can you explain your meaning?
The append is in the right place by the Docs and why I shouldn't use append in a loop?

Comment: Not better than the documentation I believe, no.

Comment: By the Docs: df.append(df2)
That is exactly what I wrote

Comment: Yes but that returns a new dataframe.

Comment: Oh, thanks, the last comment was priceless!
The solution: final_df = final_df.append(day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the df.append() function is creating a new DF that combines the primary df with the appended.

so the solution for that will be:

```
final_df = final_df.append(day)
```